# How to adjust the LineChart example from Qt Charts?

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qtcharts

I'm trying to adjust the [LineChart example](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qtcharts-linechart-example.html) from the Qt Charts library. Here's the code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();

    series->append(0, 6);
    series->append(2, 4);
    series->append(3, 8);
    series->append(7, 4);
    series->append(10, 5);
    *series << QPointF(11, 1) << QPointF(13, 3) << QPointF(17, 6) << QPointF(18, 3) << QPointF(20, 2);

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(400, 300);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I want to change the chart in a way that I can draw a point at certain x,y pairs in a different color. Now I tried to change the color of the chart line and it works, but it's not the chart line I want to change but the color of the point at x,y. Thus I guess I'll have to add points to the chart first, but apparently the API gives me only the `append()` method not something like `drawPoint()`. What do I have to do to get this functionality? Is it available already and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: What do you mean by adding points to each x,y pair? Also it would be very nice if you could maybe link to the example and maybe also draw a sketch of how it should look like in the end.

Comment: You were right, I changed the question. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is add points onto the graph at specific locations, then [QScatterSeries](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qscatterseries.html) would be the best way to do so. As far as I know, if you want each point to be a separate color, they must be contained in a separate series, as the whole series will share the same properties.

```
QScatterSeries* redSeries = new QScatterSeries;
redSeries->append(0, 6);
redSeries->append(2, 4);
redSeries->setColor(Qt::red);

QScatterSeries* blueSeries = new QScatterSeries;
blueSeries->append(3, 8);
blueSeries->append(7, 4);
blueSeries->append(10, 5);
blueSeries->setColor(Qt::blue);

...

chart->addSeries(redSeries);
chart->addSeries(blueSeries);
```